# Fading and changing elements

Tags: jquery, html

So I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/N8drz/2/

The problem is that the code below needs to be multi-purposed so I can use it in other places on my site.  So I need some abstraction help.

```
function change(){
    var showTime = 10000; // time before fade
    var fadeOutDuration = 300;
    var fadeInDuration = 500;
    var textIncrementer = 2;
    AnimateText();

    function AnimateText() {

        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery("#contactHere").fadeTo(fadeOutDuration, 0, function() {
                if (textIncrementer == 1) {
                    displayText = "Text1";
                }
                if (textIncrementer == 2) {
                    displayText = "Text2";
                }    
                if (textIncrementer == 3) {
                    displayText = "Text3";
                    textIncrementer = 0;
                }
                textIncrementer++;
                jQuery("#contactHere").html(displayText);
                jQuery("#contactHere").fadeTo(fadeInDuration, 1, function(){
                    AnimateText();
                });

            });
        }, showTime);
    }
}
```

This is good for changing a text element and works perfectly, However if I wanted to have two elements, It would cycle through them in the same way it does with the text (hiding the element, fading it in, Hiding, fading in the next one...), What would be the easiest way to do this? If needed I could use php.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well if you can throw up your HTML portion that would help.  If you are not familiar with JSFiddle go and cut in your parts into JSFiddle (Make sure you set jQuery in the framework dropdown (upper left)).. Link us the fiddle and we can give you some solutions for multi-use.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/N8drz/2/ I need info1 and info2 to cycle, I cannot just include the text as in my real thing the html contains sub divs, images etc...

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Do you mean you want more than one text element to cycle through a set of alternatives?

Comment: No, I mean this is just cycling through text, I need it to cycle through pre-defined divs (info1 and info2 in the case of the jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this, but here's one quick solution:

```
var showTime = 2000; // time before fade
var fadeOutDuration = 300;
var fadeInDuration = 500;

StartAnimation($("#contactHere"), [$("#info1"),$("#info2")]);


function StartAnimation(elem, set) {
    var textIncrementer = 0;
    AnimateText(elem, set);

    function AnimateText(elem, set) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            elem.fadeTo(fadeOutDuration, 0, function () {
                var displayText = set[textIncrementer].html();
                textIncrementer = (textIncrementer + 1) % set.length;         
                console.log(elem);
                elem.html(displayText);
                elem.fadeTo(fadeInDuration, 1, function () {
                    AnimateText(elem, set);
                });
            });
        }, showTime);
    }
}
```

I wrapped your `AnimateText` inside another function so that the index `textIncrementer` is kept private and cannot be accidently overwritten. I also stripped out the `if...else` logic and instead passed in an array of elements and used indexing to pick the correct one.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N8drz/4/)

I also just copied the html from the target divs. It might back more sense to `.detach` and `.append` the elements themselves.

Comment: @user3576711 If this solved your problem please give Matt credit and checkmark the answer.